# Java GUI Blank and nullpointerexception

Tags: java, swing, methods, nullpointerexception

I fixed that now when I click on my calculate button I get the following:

This is working all except for the calculate button now, and that is the most important part. Thank You all in advance for your help.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Radio$CalcButtonListener.actionPerformed(Radio.java:76)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)






import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;




    public class Radio extends JFrame 
    {

        private JPanel Panel;
        private JPanel buttonPanel;
        private JTextField base;
        private JTextField width;
        private JRadioButton squareArea;
        private JRadioButton parallelogramArea;
        private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 550;
        private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 550;
        double pTotal;
        double sTotal;

        public Radio()
        {
            setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            setTitle("Area Calculator");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            buildPanel();
            add(Panel);

        }


        private void buildPanel() 
        {    
            Panel = new JPanel();
            JLabel messageLabel1 = new JLabel("Please enter the base: ");
            JTextField base = new JTextField(10);
            JLabel messageLabel2 = new JLabel("Please enter the width: ");
            JTextField width = new JTextField(10);
            JRadioButton squareArea = new JRadioButton("Choice 1", true);
            JRadioButton parallelogramArea = new JRadioButton("Choice 2");
            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
            calcButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            calcButton.setForeground(Color.PINK);
            calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
            Panel.add(messageLabel1);
            Panel.add(base);
            Panel.add(messageLabel2);
            Panel.add(width);
            group.add(squareArea);
            group.add(parallelogramArea);
            Panel.add(squareArea);
            Panel.add(parallelogramArea);
            Panel.add(calcButton);
        }




        public static void main (String[] args)
        {

            Radio radio = new Radio();
            radio.buildPanel();
        }

        private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {


                if (parallelogramArea.isSelected());
                {
                    pTotal = Double.parseDouble(base.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(width.getText());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Area is: " + pTotal);
                }


                if (squareArea.isSelected())
                {

                     sTotal = Double.parseDouble(base.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(width.getText());
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Area is: " + sTotal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: More important than the answer is learning how to debug NPE's. You will need to inspect the variables on the line, find out which one is null, and then trace back into your code to see why it wasn't initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `buttonPanel` is null. But you can just debug your code line - by-line to figure out which of them is null

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate `Panel` anywhere. In `buildPanel` you can add:

```
panel = new JPanel();
```

---

Also `buttonPanel` is not initialized:

```
buttonPanel = new JPanel();
```

The panel then needs to be added to your `JFrame`:

```
add(panel);
```

Note, Java naming conventions show that variable names begin with a *lowercase* letter which would make `Panel` `panel`.

Comment: `JPanel panelName = new JPanel()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not created the object of Panel.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate Panel and buttonPanel. You can do that in the constructor.

```
    public Radio(){

        Panel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Area Calculator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildPanel();
        add(Panel);
        setVisible(true);

    }
```

Btw call buildPanel() and add the panel before you set the visibility to true.